# RabbitMq TLS/SSL connection error with Type not compatible with table constraint

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, erlang, tls1.2

I am setting up TLS for RabbitMQ and running in to issues handshake issues.

RabbitMq on establishing a connections shows

```
    error on AMQP connection <0.1019.0>: {ssl_upgrade_failure,
                                          {{{badmatch,
                                             {error,
                                              {asn1,
                                               {'Type not compatible with table constraint',
                                                {{component,'Type'},
                                                 {value,{5,<<>>}},
                                                 {unique_name_and_value,id,
                                                  {1,2,840,113549,1,1,11}}}}}}},
                                            [{public_key,pkix_decode_cert,2},
                                             {ssl_cipher,filter,2},
                                             {ssl_handshake,select_session,8},
                                             {ssl_handshake,hello,4},
                                             {ssl_connection,hello,2},
                                             {ssl_connection,next_state,3},
                                             {gen_fsm,handle_msg,7},
                                             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]},
                                           {gen_fsm,sync_send_all_state_event,
                                            [<0.1020.0>,start,5000]}}} (unknown POSIX error)
```

Question
 1) Is it an erlang issue. I run a pretty old erlang version. (Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5)) ?

2) Is it an issue with TLS version?

Extra info:

```
    ssl:versions().
    [{ssl_app,"4.1.6"},
     {supported,[tlsv1,sslv3]},
     {available,[tlsv1,sslv3]}]
```

rabbitMq Config:

```
    {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
         {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/certs/dev/ca_certificate.pem"},
                        {certfile,  "/etc/rabbitmq/certs/dev/server_certificate.pem"},
                        {keyfile,   "/etc/rabbitmq/certs/dev/server_key.pem"},
                        {verify, verify_none},
                        {depth, 3},
                        {versions, ['tlsv1.1', 'tlsv1']},
                        {fail_if_no_peer_cert, false}]}
```

Also, on running

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:5672 -cert client_certificate.pem -key  client_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
139969158874952:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 247 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE`enter code here`
Expansion: NONE
---
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: It's most likely an Erlang issue. R14B04 was released in 2011, and there have been many fixes to the ssl application since then.

Comment: similar question was in the erlang maillist. http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-April/073094.html . I guess you need erlang version that was issued after 2013 )

Comment: I was trying to fix an old set up. Upgrading erlang to latest version resolved the TLS issues. Closing the question. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to latest version of Erlang fixed the TLS issues.